# Moviepy clip alters dimensions?

Tags: python, moviepy

When I save a clip using Moviepy it changes the aspect ratio or dimensions - the result is distorted. Here is the code:

```
from moviepy.editor import *
video = VideoFileClip("/Users/src/assets/img/trialVideo.mp4").subclip(0,10)
video.write_videofile("/Users/1.mp4",fps=60)
video.save_frame("/Users/1.png", 5)
```

Both 1.mp4 and 1.png have distorted resolutions. The original video was roughly 800 height and 400 width.

Any help would be fantastic!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all pictures/videos have have same aspect ratio for example 1920x1080. Or make sure to compile it when writing the new video. My memory may fail me here, but I think you write compile=true after fps=60.

Comment: I believe you are thinking of CompositeVideoClip which requires the parameter ``compose=True`` when dealing with clips of different sizes. The OP doesn't use CompositeVideoClip, so it may be a different issue.

Comment: It would however solve his issue, but would of course require a re-write of the files which takes some time. But the issue would be fixed.